# How can I validate different types within a collection using FluentValidation?

Tags: fluentvalidation

I have a class with a collection that needs validation. The generic on the collection takes an interface and different types can be added to the collection.

What is the cleanest path forward to creating a FluentValidation validator  that supports polymorphism?

```cs
public interface IWizardStep {}

public class WizardOne : IWizardStep
{
    public string Model { get; set; }
}

public class WizardTwo : IWizardStep
{
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
}

public class Wizard
{
    public Wizard()
    {
        var w1 = new WizardOne();
        var w2 = new WizardTwo();

        Steps = new List<IWizardStep>
                    {
                        w1,
                        w2
                    };
    }

    public IList<IWizardStep> Steps { get; set; }
}

public class WizardValidator : AbstractValidator<Wizard>
{
    public WizardValidator()
    {
        RuleFor(x => x.Steps)

        // Steps First where is WizardOne
        // Model.NotEmpty()

        // Steps First where is WizardTwo
        // FirstName.NotEmpty()
    }
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

FluentValidation doesn't support polymorphism for child collections like this out of the box, but you can add this behaviour by using a custom property validator, or by using `OfType` in your rule definitions.

[I've written about both approaches before here](https://github.com/FluentValidation/FluentValidation/issues/1080#issuecomment-480267622):

## Step 1: Create a validator for each implementor

Start by creating a validator for WizardOne and WizardTwo:

```cs
public class WizardOneValidator : AbstractValidator<WizardOne> {
  public WizardOneValidator() {
    RuleFor(x => x.Model).NotEmpty();
  }
}

public class WizardTwoValidator : AbstractValidator<WizardTwo> {
  public WizardTwoValidator() {
    RuleFor(x => x.FirstName).NotEmpty();
  }
}
```

## Step 2: Create the parent validator

You have two options for defining the parent validator. The simplest approach is to use `OfType`, but this is less performant. The more complex option is to use a custom property validator.

### Option 1: Using OfType

```cs
public WizardValidator : AbstractValidator<Wizard> {
  public WizardValidator() {
    RuleForEach(x => x.Steps.OfType<WizardOne>()).SetValidator(new WizardOneValidator());
    RuleForEach(x => x.Steps.OfType<WizardTwo>()).SetValidator(new WizardTwoValidator());
  }
}
```

This is the simplest approach, but calling `OfType` inside the call `RuleFor` will end up bypassing FluentValidation's expression cache, which is a potential performance hit. It also iterates the collection multiple. This may or may not be an issue for you - you'll need to decide if this has any real-world impact on your application.

### Option 2: Using a custom PropertyValidator.

This uses a custom custom validator which can differentiate the underlying type at runtime:

```cs
public WizardValidator : AbstractValidator<Wizard> {
  public WizardValidator() {
    RuleForEach(x => x.Steps).SetValidator(new PolymorphicValidator<Wizard, IWizardStep>()
      .Add<WizardOne>(new WizardOneValidator())
      .Add<WizardTwo>(new WizardTwoValidator())
    );
  }
}
```

Syntactically, this isn't quite as nice, but doesn't bypass the expression cache and doesn't iterate the collection multiple times. This is the code for the `PolymorphicValidator`:

```cs
public class PolymorphicValidator<T, TInterface> : ChildValidatorAdaptor<T, TInterface> {
    readonly Dictionary<Type, IValidator> _derivedValidators = new Dictionary<Type, IValidator>();

    // Need the base constructor call, even though we're just passing null.
    public PolymorphicValidator() : base((IValidator<TInterface>)null, typeof(IValidator<TInterface>))  {
    }

    public PolymorphicValidator<T, TInterface> Add<TDerived>(IValidator<TDerived> derivedValidator) where TDerived : TInterface {
        _derivedValidators[typeof(TDerived)] = derivedValidator;
        return this;
    }

    public override IValidator<TInterface> GetValidator(PropertyValidatorContext context) {
        // bail out if the current item is null
        if (context.PropertyValue == null) return null;

        if (_derivedValidators.TryGetValue(context.PropertyValue.GetType(), out var derivedValidator)) {
            return new ValidatorWrapper(derivedValidator);
        }

        return null;
    }

    private class ValidatorWrapper : AbstractValidator<TInterface> {

        private IValidator _innerValidator;
        public ValidatorWrapper(IValidator innerValidator) {
            _innerValidator = innerValidator;
        }

        public override ValidationResult Validate(ValidationContext<TInterface> context) {
            return _innerValidator.Validate(context);
        }

        public override Task<ValidationResult> ValidateAsync(ValidationContext<TInterface> context, CancellationToken cancellation = new CancellationToken()) {
            return _innerValidator.ValidateAsync(context, cancellation);
        }

        public override IValidatorDescriptor CreateDescriptor() {
            return _innerValidator.CreateDescriptor();
        }
    }
}
```

This will probably be implemented in the library as a first class feature at some point in the future - [you can track its development here if you're interested](https://github.com/FluentValidation/FluentValidation/issues/1237).