# FluentValidation - Validate interfaced child properties

Tags: fluentvalidation

I'm trying to apply FluentValidation (v 9.1.1) on a tree structure, using the visitor pattern. The special thing about it is, that a couple of different tree elements all implement an interface and the child properties of the elements are of this interface type. In other words, the child properties are not strongly typed. Simplified model see below. Each validator goes on the specific implementation and I don't get the point, how to attach child validators for *interface* children.

Here is a demo model (working code):

```cs
public interface IElement
{
    Type ResultType { get; }
    TResult Accept<TResult>(IElementVisitor<TResult> visitor);
}

public class ConstElement : IElement
{
    public object Value { get; set; }
    public Type ResultType => Value?.GetType();
    public TResult Accept<TResult>(IElementVisitor<TResult> visitor)
    {
        return visitor.VisitElement(this);
    }
}

public class BinaryElement : IElement
{
    // Child properties are not strongly typed.
    public IElement Left { get; set; }
    public IElement Right { get; set; }
    public Operand Operand { get; set; }
    public Type ResultType => Operand switch
    {
        Operand.Equal => typeof(bool),
        Operand.GreaterThan => typeof(bool),
        Operand.Plus => Left.GetType(),
        Operand.Multiply => Left.GetType(),
        _ => throw new NotImplementedException(),
    };
    public TResult Accept<TResult>(IElementVisitor<TResult> visitor)
    {
        return visitor.VisitElement(this);
    }
}

public enum Operand { Equal, GreaterThan, Plus, Multiply }

public class ConstElementValidator : AbstractValidator<ConstElement>
{
    public ConstElementValidator()
    {
        RuleFor(ele => ele.Value).NotNull().Must(value => (value is double) || (value is TimeSpan));
    }
}

public class BinaryElementValidator : AbstractValidator<BinaryElement>
{
    public BinaryElementValidator()
    {
        // Rules for the element itself
        RuleFor(ele => ele.Left).NotNull();
        RuleFor(ele => ele.Right).NotNull();
        RuleFor(ele => ele).Must(ele => IsValidResultTypeCombination(ele.Left.ResultType, ele.Right.ResultType, ele.Operand));
        // Add rules for child elements here? How?
    }
    private bool IsValidResultTypeCombination(Type left, Type right, Operand operand)
    {
        if (left == typeof(bool) && right != typeof(bool))
            return false;
        // other result type validations...
        return true;
    }
}

public interface IElementVisitor<TResult>
{
    TResult VisitElement(ConstElement element);
    TResult VisitElement(BinaryElement element);
}

public class ValidationVisitor : IElementVisitor<ValidationResult>
{
    public ValidationResult VisitElement(ConstElement element)
    {
        return new ConstElementValidator().Validate(element);
    }

    public ValidationResult VisitElement(BinaryElement element)
    {
        // How to add validation of element.Left and element.Right, 
        // taking into account, that their type is IElement, while Validators are bound to the implementation type?
        var result = new BinaryElementValidator().Validate(element);
        var leftResult = element.Left.Accept(this);
        var rightResult = element.Right.Accept(this);
        // merge leftResult and rightResult with result
        return result;
    }
}
```

In general, there are two ways to add child validation. Either calling child validators directly in the validators, which would make the ValidationVisitor obsolete, or let focus the validators on their own logic and adding child validation in the ValidationVisitor, as shown in the code.

The only way I am able to proceed right now is by using the visitor and merging the validation results of an element and its child elements.

Is there a way to add child validators to the BinaryElement in this scenario? Either in the visitor or in the BinaryElementValidator directly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's a couple of different ways to do this. You can either define multiple rules for each of the interface implementors, or you can use a custom property validator to do runtime inspection on the type. This is similar to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63378699/how-can-i-validate-different-types-within-a-collection-using-fluentvalidation).

## Option 1: Multiple rule definitions with a type filter

With this option, you create a specific rule definition for each potential implementor of the interface:

```cs
// Inside your BinaryElementValidator use a safe cast inside the RuleFor definition. 
// If it isn't the right type, the child validator won't be executed 
// as child validators aren't run for null properties.

RuleFor(x => x.Left as BinaryElement).SetValidator(new BinaryElementValidator());
RuleFor(x => x.Left as ConstElement).SetValidator(new ConstElementValidator());

RuleFor(x => x.Right as BinaryElement).SetValidator(new BinaryElementValidator());
RuleFor(x => x.Right as ConstElement).SetValidator(new ConstElementValidator());
```

This is the simplest approach, but by having a more complex expression within the call to `RuleFor` you will be bypassing FluentValidation's expression cache, which will be a performance hit if you're instantiating the validator many times. I'll leave it for you to decide if that would be an issue in your application.

You may need to call `OverridePropertyName` for each rule too, as FluentValidation won't be able to infer the name of the property with this approach.

## Option 2: A custom property validator

A slightly more complex solution, but means you can stick with simple property expressions inside RuleFor, meaning you won't bypass the cache. This makes use of a custom validator called `PolymorphicValidator`, which will inspect the type of the property at runtime.

```cs
RuleFor(x => x.Left).SetValidator(new PolymorphicValidator<BinaryElement, IElement>()
  .Add<BinaryElement>(new BinaryElementValidator())
  .Add<ConstElement>(new ConstElementValidator())
);

RuleFor(x => x.Right).SetValidator(new PolymorphicValidator<BinaryElement, IElement>()
  .Add<BinaryElement>(new BinaryElementValidator())
  .Add<ConstElement(new ConstElementValidator())
);
```

And here's the code for the `PolymorphicValidator`:

```cs
public class PolymorphicValidator<T, TInterface> : ChildValidatorAdaptor<T, TInterface> {
    readonly Dictionary<Type, IValidator> _derivedValidators = new Dictionary<Type, IValidator>();

    // Need the base constructor call, even though we're just passing null.
    public PolymorphicValidator() : base((IValidator<TInterface>)null, typeof(IValidator<TInterface>))  {
    }

    public PolymorphicValidator<T, TInterface> Add<TDerived>(IValidator<TDerived> derivedValidator) where TDerived : TInterface {
        _derivedValidators[typeof(TDerived)] = derivedValidator;
        return this;
    }

    public override IValidator<TInterface> GetValidator(PropertyValidatorContext context) {
        // bail out if the current item is null
        if (context.PropertyValue == null) return null;

        if (_derivedValidators.TryGetValue(context.PropertyValue.GetType(), out var derivedValidator)) {
            return new ValidatorWrapper(derivedValidator);
        }

        return null;
    }

    private class ValidatorWrapper : AbstractValidator<TInterface> {

        private IValidator _innerValidator;
        public ValidatorWrapper(IValidator innerValidator) {
            _innerValidator = innerValidator;
        }

        public override ValidationResult Validate(ValidationContext<TInterface> context) {
            return _innerValidator.Validate(context);
        }

        public override Task<ValidationResult> ValidateAsync(ValidationContext<TInterface> context, CancellationToken cancellation = new CancellationToken()) {
            return _innerValidator.ValidateAsync(context, cancellation);
        }

        public override IValidatorDescriptor CreateDescriptor() {
            return _innerValidator.CreateDescriptor();
        }
    }
}
```

This approach is actually going to be added to the library in a future version - you can track its development here if you're interested: https://github.com/FluentValidation/FluentValidation/issues/1237

Comment: If you go with the second option, I think you'll want to tweak the solution slightly so that the `Add` methods take a callback func, otherwise you'll get in an infinite loop when instantiating the BinaryElementValidator.